# утечка памяти Python

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe

Всем добрый день, имеется проблема утечки памяти в парсере на питоне, которая приводит к тому, что если очень долго держать скрипт включенным то он начинает сжирать всю память. Если кто поможет, буду очень благодарен. Код ниже.

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1], 'last': [1], 'lowestAsk': [1], 'highestBid': [1], 'percentChange': [1], 'baseVolume': [1], 'quoteVolume': [1], 'isFrozen': [1], 'high24hr': [1], 'low24hr': [1], 'date': [1]})
while 1:
    try:
        url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker'
        responce = requests.get(url, timeout=10).json()['USDT_BTC']
        url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTradeHistory&currencyPair=USDT_BTC'
        responce.update({'date':requests.get(url, timeout=10).json()[0]['date']})
        if abs(float(responce['lowestAsk'])-float(data['lowestAsk'].tolist()[-1]))>1:
            data=data.append(responce,ignore_index=True)
            data=data.drop(data.index[[0]])
            data.to_csv('pol1.csv',mode='a',header=False)
        del url,responce
    except:
        sys.stdout.write('pol тупит')
```

Comment: А как чем/профилировали процесс?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
url1 = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker'
url2 = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTradeHistory&currencyPair=USDT_BTC'

prev_lowestAsk = 0

while True:
    try:
        r = requests.get(url1, timeout=10).json()['USDT_BTC']
        r.update({'date':requests.get(url2, timeout=10).json()[0]['date']})

        if abs(r['lowestAsk'] - prev_lowestAsk > 1):
            pd.DataFrame(r, index=[0]).to_csv('c:/temp/pol1.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)

        prev_lowestAsk = r['lowestAsk']
    except:
        sys.stdout.write('pol тупит')
```

Comment: попробовал, память продолжает утекать

Comment: @Иван, тогда надо ["копать"](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/muppy.html)